# Ruled paper aspect in emacs interface

Tags: customize

Is it possible to have ruled lines in emacs? I would like to have the same look of a notebook while writing my org files.

Comment: looks like a feature request to me.

Comment: You may add the /Box/ property to the `default` face, but I'm afraid all of your Emacs will look quite ugly. `M-x customize-face`

Comment: The form-feed character `#x0C` can be displayed as horizontal line with the packages [`form-feed`](https://github.com/wasamasa/form-feed) and [`page-break-lines`](https://github.com/purcell/page-break-lines). Pityingly it would cause double-line spacing if this technique was used for newlines. Maybe the lines can be squeezed a bit.

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but if it does turn out to be a feature request, it's likely to be low priority since it would be a purely visual rather than functional feature.

Comment: It should already be feasible on elisp level. One could pad the visible part of the buffer with spaces (maybe with the after-string text property) and use some underlined face.